# HQL Query implementation

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g, hql

I'm new in Hibernate and I'm developing an application with Hibernate. In concrete, I'm trying to implement the following SQL Query with Hibernate:

```
select * from ifcitsv2013 where timestamp between startDate and finishDate and id = '50'
```

In Hibernate, I have the following code for the query:

```
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(IfcitsSensorphistory.class).add(Property.forName("id").eq(sDevice) );
List<Ifcitsv2013> readings = session.createCriteria(Ifcitsv2013.class).add(Property.forName("ifcitsSensorphistory").gt(dc)).list();
```

The mapping class `Ifcitsv2013` is as follows:

```
public class Ifcitsv2013 implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private long readingid;
    private IfcitsSensorphistory ifcitsSensorphistory;
    private Timestamp timestamp;
    private String value;
    private String direction;
    private String quality;
    private String status;
```

and the class `IfcitsSensorphistory` is:

```
public class IfcitsSensorphistory {
    private String id;
    private String description;
    private Timestamp starttime;
    private Timestamp endtime;
    private String timeseriesdatatype;
    private String dataorigin;
    private String usagedefineddataorigin;
    private String unit;
    private String value;
```

When I execute the query, I've got the `Exception`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getProjectedTypes(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:362)
at org.hibernate.criterion.SubqueryExpression.createAndSetInnerQuery(SubqueryExpression.java:153)
at org.hibernate.criterion.SubqueryExpression.toSqlString(SubqueryExpression.java:69)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getWhereCondition(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:380)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:114)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:83)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.<init>(CriteriaLoader.java:92)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1687)
at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
at com.cartif.dwhconnector.manager.DatabaseCommunicator.retrieveHistoricalData(DatabaseCommunicator.java:242)
at com.cartif.dwhconnector.manager.DWHManager.retrieveData(DWHManager.java:62)
at unittest.DWHConnectorTester.main(DWHConnectorTester.java:31)
```

Could anyone help me to develop the proper query?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an open `session`.

```
Query q = session.CreateQuery("select * from Ifcitsv2013 left join IfcitsSensorphistory as h where timestamp between :startDate and :finishDate and h.id = 50");
q.setDate("startDate", startDate);
q.setDate("finishDate", finishDate);
List result = q.list();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I am sure the session is opened, the problem comes from the relationship between the id column of the table Ifcitsv2013 which is not a direct attribute in the class, but a relationship with the table IfcitsSensorphistory

Comment: Sure, to have an attribute from another table you should join that table in the query.